# Remove ratings from output tab and add it in after product summary

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using an already purchased wordpress theme. The rating tab is located under "woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs". I already know how to unset it from the output tabs but I don't know how to add it in "woocommerce_after_single_product_summary". Did you do something similar to this?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, create a [Child Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) so that your modifications do not get overridden when any Theme Updates are released.

Head into your `functions.php`, in your Parent Theme, and locate the function entry for your Ratings Tab.  Copy this coding into the `functions.php` file, within your Child Theme.

Within the `add_action` entry, you will need to change the code as follows:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'THIS_NEEDS_TO_BE_THE_SAME_AS_THE_FUNCTION_NAME');
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_rating', 10, 2 ); 

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_rating', 10 ); 

function woocommerce_template_single_rating( $woocommerce_template_single_title, $int ) { 
    // make action magic happen here... 
};
```

Comment: I had tried this with no effect whatsoever. I think is because the theme I'm using is not using the 'wocommerce_template_single_rating' but it is instead the rating is stored in the "woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs".